# Can't publish application in Continuous Integration

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration, webdeploy

I have the following configuration in `Continuous Integration CI`

[image]

Build runs successfully but the publish part is not working. My publish profile using a web deploy to deploy on server directly. Web deploy working fine if i run it from the normal publish.

Any suggestion on solving this issue?

Comment: "Not working" is very broad. Can you state the **exact** behavior you're seeing?

Comment: It's not working means the web deploy didn't deploy to my server

Comment: Did you got  any error information during the publish? Could you provide some related messages in the build logs?

Comment: there is no error in publish the build just completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the reason of my-- the PublishUrl isn't used. Workaroud for me change the webdeploy to xcopy.

Comment: The webdeploy it self works fine but when i am trying to run it from Continuous Integration its not working or even called